# Android Material CalendarView Selected Date Background Radius

Tags: java, android, xml, frontend, calendarview

Hi there I'm currently working with the Material CalendarView Library

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Everything is working fine but I'm trying to reduce the radius of the round background which is appearing when a User selects a date.

Because this is way too big:

[image]

My code currently looks like this:

```
<com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/CalenderViewCustom"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    app:mcv_weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewWeekCustomText"
    app:mcv_headerTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewHeaderCustomText"
    android:dateTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewDateCustomText"
    android:weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewWeekCustomText">
</com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView>
```

styles.xml:

```
 <style name="CalenderViewCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat">s
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/mainSelectedColor</item>
    <item name="android:headerYearTextAppearance">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:headerMonthTextAppearance">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:headerDayOfMonthTextAppearance">@color/colorBlack</item>

</style>

<style name="CalenderViewDateCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>

</style>

<style name="CalenderViewWeekCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
</style>


<style name="CalenderViewHeaderCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
</style>
```

Does anyone know a solution for this ?

Comment: Have you find out the solution for this? I am also facing same issue of reducing the selector size in this.